# How to animate 3d charts of Zingchart?

Tags: animation, zingchart

As per [official](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/json-configuration/graphset/plot/animation/) documentation of zingcharts, adding following code snippet in json configuration for my bar chart should initiate animation:

```
"plot":{
"animation":{
    "effect":"2",
    "method":"3",
    "sequence":"ANIMATION_BY_PLOT",
    "speed":"ANIMATION_FAST"
}
```

}

But this works only for 2d charts. Does that mean, 3d zingcharts cannot be animated or am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot animate 3d charts.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for reply. Actually this is not written,in any zingchart documentation (at least in those which I referred) that we cannot animate 3d charts. It would be great however if Zingchart thinks about enabling animation on 3d charts or at least mention this somewhere in documentation. Well lets hope this gets implemented in near future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment by @nardecky and from **support ticket** I opened in Zingchart, It is confirmed that

> 3d charts cannot be animated and is not planned to be implemented at least in near future.

[image: zingchart]